How to concatenate strings containing asterisks in bash
I have 2 variables:
file1=file1_*.txt
file2=file2_*.txt

The actual names of the files are: file1_FY24Q3.txt and file2_FY24Q3.txt and they change every quarter. I want to concatenate these vars into one string. I tried this:
files="${file1},${file2}"

But this doesn't work and echo $files prints file1_*.txt,file2_*.txt.
Why doesn't it work and what is the correct way to concatenate the strings?

Please [edit] your question and describe the expected behavior. Are you expecting $files to be file1_FY24Q3.txtfile2_FY24Q3.txt or file1_*.txtfile2_*.txt or file1_FY24Q3.txt,file2_FY24Q3.txt or something else? Concatenating strings is just var3="$var1""$var2", but I don't think that's what you really want. How do you want to use this? What is the end objective here?

Note that your post says nothing about you wanting to expand the globs. You have two strings that contain asterisks, and the result of your last commands shows they got concatenated just fine, asterisks and all. (along with the comma you added, of course.) Given you already know how to concatenate strings, is the actual question about how to expand the two globs?


Why doesn't it work

because when you wrote file1=file1_*.txt, there was no file name expansion (what is often called "globbing") done; just the literal string "f", "i", "l", "e", "1", "_", "*", ".", "t"… was stored.

and what is the correct way to concatenate the strings?

You need to do the filename expansion!
I.e. do something like this:
filename1=file1_*.txt
filename2=file2_*.txt
IFS=
shopt -s nullglob
actual_files=( $filename1 $filename2 )
files_comma_separated="${actual_files[0]},${actual_files[1]}"
# or, if you don't know how many files will match:
files_comma_sep="$(printf ',%s' $actual_files | tail -c +2)"

The unquoted expansion of $filename1 and $filename2 will cause the globs to expand, while setting IFS to the empty string beforehand will prevent word splitting (which would otherwise mess up patterns with whitespace in them).
Note that the array actual_files will now contain all matches produced by the globs: there might be more than two. If one of the patterns does not match, nullglob will cause it to be removed instead of returning the unmodified pattern.

Thank you, Marcus! Can you please explain more on the first point? You say that the variable stores the literals. However, when I do echo $file1 it prints file1_FY24Q3.txt and not file1_*.txt.

yes, because echo without " around the single variable, and no other characters around that variable, "magically" (read: iconsistently, imho) does the file name expansion.

Not quite. actual_files only contains 2 elements, the literal file1_*.txt and file2_*.txt. The glob patterns don't get expanded until printf, and even then you only get file1_*.txt expanded -- because actual_files is an array and $actual_files only returns the first element. To get the files expanded into the  array, you need the pattern variables unquoted: actual_files=( $filename1 $filename2 ), and then you need to worry about word splitting on the variable values before the glob expansion happens.

@ilkkachu fname=Documen* ; echo $fname yields Documents, while fname=Documen* ; echo $fname, yields Documen*,. I find that hard to motivate.

@ilkkachu I find it hard to understand when filename expansion does and doesn't happen. I need to memorize the cases it doesn't, I find, and while "appending a character after the variable name makes the shell not do filename expansion" is somewhat understandable, "oh and if filename expansion fails, you get the unexpanded string, so what the shell does there with the string is directory-dependent" is just inconsistent.

@MarcusMüller, it always happens when you have an unquoted expansion. echo $fname, tries to expand the pattern Documen*,, which would match e.g. Documenasdf,. And yes, if there are no matches, you get the unmodified pattern back. Frankly, I see that as perfectly consistent. Just that I can well understand that being rather less than useful in many cases... But I suppose that's why csh and zsh do it differently.

Anyway, if not done like that, the question is what would be better? Fail if any glob gives no matches? But that would mess up things like for file in *.txt in scripts... Expand to nothing if there are no matches? But that would make ls *.foo do something different... Should we have some heuristic smarts there? What if there's multiple globs where some match and others don't? (csh has its own smarts here) Or should we just append the (N) if we want the glob to be removed when not matching...

I think the heuristics "smarts" is what bash currently tries to do, i.e. expand if there is a match. I personally think: "a glob was specified, and no modifiers clarifying it's OK to be empty were specified, so we must fail when expansion fails" would be a sensible way forward.

@MarcusMüller, I wouldn't call the current behaviour heuristic. I mean, it's a perfectly simple decision and always works the same way. Something like looking at the context to have the same glob do different things in different situations (like for file in *.foo vs. ls *.foo) would be another thing entirely. But yeah, I guess shopt -s failglob would be for you, then.

Another way, something like this
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s nullglob
all_files=(file1_FY*.txt file2_FY*.txt)
# all_files=(file[1-9]*_FY*.txt) #: If unknown number of file names
shopt -u nullglob

formater()(
  IFS=,;printf '%s' "$*"
)

formater "${all_files[@]}"

#: In a variable
# files=$(IFS=,;printf '%s' "${all_files[*]}")
# files=$(formater "${all_files[@]}")



The glob [1-9] might be affected by you LOCALE see Locale
